# Angular cli build error

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

I'm new with Angular2 and Angular-cli and this is the 1st time I use

```
nb build --prod
```

and I have back this error:

```
ERROR in ng:../src/app/search/search.component.html (3,1): Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

if I go in the search.component.html file I can read in the 1st rows

```
<div class="full-recap" #test >
  <div class="box box-title {{search.target.definition}}">
    <h2 class="vertical">Target</h2>
    <div class="row recap" [innerHTML]="search.target.getRecap()"> </div>
  </div>
... etc etc
```

in my .ts file I have:

```
@ViewChild('test') el: ElementRef;
```

to define the #test element.

Can anyone suggest me where is the issue? Did I miswrote something?

Comment: you cant put {{item}} bindings inside of the class attribute you'd want 

<div class="..." [ngClass]="search.target.definition">

if thats what you're trying to do there. or is that meant to be inside there?
<div class="...">{{search.target.definition}}
...
</div>

Comment: thank you @MatthewOptionalMeehan this solved it ^^

Comment: can you post the working component html as an answer below for others to see